# Does C-Brite require rinsing

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer

I've read online that C-Brite:

1. Does require rinsing
2. Does not require rinsing
3. Does not require rinsing if you let it dry
4. Does not require rinsing but you should or your beer will have off flavors

Additionally, any concerns about re-introducing baddies with tap water (not boiled) when rinsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all the info you want is at [their home page](http://www.fallbright.com/newsc_brite.htm) (relevant snippets below):

> The formulation of our C-Brite is a federally approved sanitizer...we
>   learned last year...that sanitizers must be registered on a
>   State-by-State basis...neither we nor our producer is willing to
>   do....we have had to take the product and sell it as a cleanser
>   instead, just like we did with B-Brite years ago.
>
> ...sanitizers can be ‘no-rinse’ when used in the proper
>   concentrations...no cleansers are permitted to be labeled
>   ‘no-rinse’...we changed the packaging on C-Brite from ‘sanitizer’ to
>   ‘cleanser’, even though we did not change the formulation at all.
>
> **SANITIZATION**:  No-rinse effective sanitization requires a solution of 100 ppm available chlorine.  This will be achieved by dissolving
>   the contents of an 0.8 ounce packet of C-Brite in 2 gallons of warm
>   water.  Thoroughly wet all surfaces to be sanitized.  Let stand at
>   least one minute.  **Drain and AIR DRY.**

As for rinsing, I think as long as the water is clean and drinkable, there won't be issues with it contaminating your items.  That said, I still prefer a no-rinse, wet-contact solution like [Star-San](http://www.fivestarchemicals.com/breweries/homebrewing/products/).

Comment: Thanks.  I've read that, but I wanted to get real-world feedback.  Does it leave a taste?  Air drying seems like it gives time to recontaminate via air-borne.  Plus I typically sanitize right before I use my equipment, not days before.  I'm eager to see what other people have experienced.  I may try out Star-San, I haven't used before.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well, for at least 1-3, I would think the manufacturer should be the last word, as homebrewers will be hard pressed to prove that an infection was due to letting the sanitizer dry, or not rinsing.

Comment: For what it is worth, my routine is PBW -> Rinse -> StarSan (no rinse).